# Please explain the algorithm for finding bridges in graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, graph-traversal, java

let, low[] and disc[] be two 1D arrays

**disc[i]** stores the discovery time of node[I]

**low[i]** stores the lowest value between disc[i] and discovery time of children of node[i]

I'm curious that what is difference between **low[u] = Math.min(low[u], disc[v]);**
and **low[u] = Math.min(low[u], low[v]);**

why is later incorrect?

The following is the code for finding the bridges in a graph.

````
    private static void dfs(int u, List<Integer>[] g, boolean[] visited, int[] parent, int[] low,
            int[] disc, List<String> bridges) {
        visited[u] = true;
        disc[u] = low[u] = ++time;

        if(g[u] != null)
            for (int v : g[u]) {
                if(visited[v] && parent[u] != v)
                    low[u] = Math.min(low[u], disc[v]);
                if(!visited[v]){
                    parent[v] = u;
                    dfs(v, g, visited, parent, low, disc, bridges);
                    low[u] = Math.min(low[u], low[v]);
                    if(low[v] > disc[u])
                        bridges.add(String.format("%d -> %d",u,v));
                }
            }        
    }
```
````

Comment: We're not a coding site.  Asking us to explain code to you is probably not a good fit here.  Any community votes?  P.S. Have you tried running both versions of the code on many randomly generated graphs to look for one where they give different results?

Comment: _Have you tried running both versions of the code on many randomly generated graphs to look for one where they give different results?_ **no**. I was thinking about it.

Comment: Have you read the original paper "Depth-First Search and Linear Graph Algorithms" by Tarjan? I think that it represents this topic better than any other resource available in internet.

Comment: Thanks, @Laakeri for recommending me this beautiful paper.